# Limit refs shown with git log --decorate

Tags: git, git-log

I have 3 standard remotes for a the main repository I work in currently: a local backup, my development partner's workstation, and a hosted repository.  We have 3 or 4 branches that are active most of the time, one being master.

I monitor the branches on a regular basis throughout the day using:

```
git log --graph --oneline --decorate -15 my-branch his-repo/his-branch master other-branch
```

`--decorate` is crucial because it lets me know the state of things in regards to our very volatile development branches.  The problem is that I see ***all*** of the remote refs and ***all*** of the branches, tags, etc. in the decoration.

Is there any way to limit `--decorate` to only output certain refs?  Listing the refs on the command line only limits the commits shown, not the refs shown.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot limit this out-of-the box. But nothing is stopping you from scripting the manipulation of .git/refs and then restoring it right after :).

Comment: Manipulating `refs` isn't a bad idea except that I also have to take into account `packed-refs`.  Though perhaps once I wrote the script it would find other uses...  Then again, a hard-coded script to rename `refs` and `packed-refs` and insert a simple `packed-refs` file with the correct hashes might be fairly straight-forward.  The biggest danger I see in this is any other processes that might be accessing the repo (IDEs, etc.).

Comment: I never integrate source control with any IDE. Then again, I'm in the .NET world where there is no trust of OSS ;)

Comment: I'm in .NET mostly as well.  I use the git source control provider mainly for doing a quick diff, history, or blame.  I use TortoiseGit mainly for the Show Log.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with [Git 2.16](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/2.16.0#git-log---decorate-refsltpatterngt), the option `--decorate-refs-exclude` allows:

> **--decorate-refs=**
> **--decorate-refs-exclude=**
>
> If no --decorate-refs is given, pretend as if all refs were included. For each candidate, do not use it for decoration if it
> matches any patterns given to --decorate-refs-exclude or if it doesn’t
> match any of the patterns given to --decorate-refs.

Answer (score 3):

No. If you're using decorate, it will use all available names as decorations. `--decorate=short` will reduce the clutter, but not reduce the total number of decorations you're going to be looking at.

You could write a script which decorates the output of `git log` yourself quite easily, if you need this specific functionality.

Comment: Decorating myself might be an option. I'd have to preserve the `--graph` formatting, since the graph and the decorations are key to what I'm monitoring.  Perhaps using `cut` and `paste` would work.

Comment: @MikeJansen if you end up scripting something like this, please share :)

Comment: @TobyJ - I did not :(  Necessity hasn't been great enough to get me to spend the time on it and not enough spare cycles to do it for fun.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
git log --decorate-refs-exclude 'refs/tags/*'
```