# git log without tags

Tags: git, git-log

So I'm doing something like

```
 git log --graph --pretty='%h %d %s' -n10
```

to get brief history of my recent commits.

The only issue I have is that most of the time I'm not interested in seeing the tags, only the branches.  %d however shows both tags and branches.  Is there some way I can only display branch names and not tags?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit refs shown with git log --decorate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366960/limit-refs-shown-with-git-log-decorate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`git log --format="%C(auto) %h %s"`

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. The question asked for removing tags while keeping branch names. This also removes branch names.

Comment: @Jet I clearly didn't read the question carefully. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ As far a I can tell, it is not possible to do exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71201009/11895 seems to be doing the job

Answer (score 14):

A bit late to the party, but I have just encountered the same issue.

This should display everything except tags:

```
git log --decorate-refs-exclude=refs/tags --pretty='%h %d %s' -n10
```

Answer (score -2):

add this to your `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
        blog = log --graph --oneline --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset - %C(yellow)%s%Creset %C(green)<%an>%Creset %C(blue)@%d%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

This way you get only the commit number, message how made the commit and in which branch it was committed. and you only have to type `git blog` and you can look at colors when you want

and if you really only the branch name just do:

`git log --graph --oneline --pretty=format:'%C(blue)@%d%Creset'`

Comment: git log --graph --oneline --pretty=format:'%C(blue)@%d%Creset' still shows the tags too.

Comment: for k in `git branch|perl -pe s/^..//`;do echo -e `git show --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" $k|head -n 1`\\t$k;done|sort -r

Comment: @Jistanidiot try `git log --branches --remotes --tags --graph --oneline --decorate`

Comment: I get a "syntax error near unexpected token '|'" and the 2nd one still shows tags...but I think I can possibly figure something out to remove them since they are now labeled "tag:"

Comment: @Jistanidiot Like so `for k in git branch|perl -pe s/^..//;do echo -e git show --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" $k|head -n 1\\t$k;done|sort -r`

Comment: Yes starting with for k in.. and ending with |sort -r  bash doesn't like it for some reason.

Comment: RHEL 5 gives the first error.  On Debian I get something similar except the unexpected token is "do" and not "|"

Comment: @Jistanidiot Okay how about this...............
**for k in `git branch|perl -pe s/^..//`;do echo -e `git show --pretty=format:"%Cgreen%ci %Cblue%cr%Creset" $k|head -n 1`\\t$k;done|sort -r**

Comment: @Jistanidiot here look at [this](http://illwind.thecrazy.me/only-for-jistanidiot--pageid5).

Answer (score -3):

Check out `git log --help` and specifically `%d` option:

```
%d: ref names, like the --decorate option of git-log(1)
```

This is your tags. So all you have to do is to drop it from your command, i.e.:

```
git log --graph --pretty='%h %s' -n10
```

Comment: OP asked to keep branches, the above command removes them as well.